# I don't see images in Outlook. I just see a red X

Tags: outlook

Outlook 2003 will get into a situation where it will no longer render images in the preview pane or the message window.

If you reply to the message, then you will see the image.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from:

http://www.shahine.com/omar/FixingOutlookRedXProblem.aspx

Locate the Outlook Temporary Items folder by opening the Registry and locating

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Security\OutlookSecureTempFolder

1. Navigate to the value of this Key. It should be something like: %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\OLK3D\ where OLK3D is some randomly generated string that always starts with OLK
2. Quit Outlook
3. Delete the contents of the folder
4. Launch Outlook

Comment: Damn! you beat me to it! :-P

Comment: LOL, this is the #1 hit on my blog. I figured it would be a popular question here as well!

Comment: Great, it worked for me!